# 'uint32_t' does not name a type

Tags: c++, uint32-t, cstdint

I'm trying to compile a C++ software package that was written in 2007 and I'm getting this error:

`error: ‘uint32_t’ does not name a type`

This is happening in 64-bit Ubuntu using g++ 4.5.2. It compiles fine on 64-bit CentOS using g++ 4.1.2.

Is there an `#include` or a compiler flag that I'm missing? Or, should I use `typedef` to assign `uint32_t` to a `size_t` or maybe an `unsigned int`?

Comment: Look for stdint.h or <cstdint> headers.  That type is (as I understand it) part of C99 but didn't make it into C++.

Comment: Did you `#include <stdint.h>`? Looks like a possible bug on 64 bit Ubuntu. Also, do you have a `-std=c++98` or some such command line option for gcc? If so, can you check if it compiles fine if you use `-std=gnu++98`?

Comment: @dirkgently I checked the Makefile and there were no `std` options.

Comment: @user667810: So that defaults to GNU extensions and C++98 mode.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

You need to include stdint.h

```
 #include <stdint.h>
```

Comment: The "proper" C++ header would be `cstdint`.

Comment: Note, in my case the problem was actually that the include `boost/cstdint.hpp` was not found. `yum install boost-devel` fixed my case.

Comment: @paxdiablo shouldn't the cstdint.h be included inside an extern "C" { } block?

Comment: @paxdiablo the 'proper' header gave me "#error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental ..." Yeah, yeah, should upgrade, but it's an enormous old app that barely made it into 64-bit world.

Comment: What about `C` with GCC?

Comment: @Royi - same thing.  `<stdint.h>` will work in both C and C++ with any compiler.

Comment: @StarShine all C standard library headers include `extern "C"` wrappers in conditional compilation for `defined __cplusplus`.  You would only need that is using some extraordinarily old headers.

Comment: @paxdiablo 'proper' is not that helpful if supporting legacy code where you want  `int32_t` in the global namespace as would have been the case when C++98 was current so did not include C99 headers.  You could include cstdint, and then issue multiple `using` directives, but stdint.h is the path of least resistance.

Answer (score 43):

You need to `#include <cstdint>`, but that may not always work.

The problem is that some compiler often automatically export names defined in various headers or provided types before such standards were in place.

Now, I said "may not always work." That's because the cstdint header is part of the C++11 standard and is not always available on current C++ compilers (but often is). The stdint.h header is the C equivalent and is part of C99.

For best portability, I'd recommend using Boost's `boost/cstdint.hpp` header, if you're willing to use boost. Otherwise, you'll probably be able to get away with #include'ing `<cstdint>`.

Comment: This gave me `#error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.`

Comment: Right, as it says, cstdint is part of the new C++ standard (which was called C++0x but is not, officially, C++11. So to use that header, you have to enable the new standard in g++. Like I said, the best portable way to get these types is to use Boost or some other equivalent header, rather than relying on compiler support.

Answer (score 12):

I also encountered the same problem on Mac OSX 10.6.8 and unfortunately adding `#include <stdint.h>` or `<cstdint.h>` to the corresponding file did not solve my problem. However, after more search, I found this solution advicing to add `#include <sys/types.h>` which worked well for me!

Answer (score 8):

The other answers assume that your compiler is C++11 compliant. That is fine if it is. But what if you are using an older compiler?

I picked up the following hack somewhere on the net. It works well enough for me:

```
  #if defined __UINT32_MAX__ or UINT32_MAX
  #include <inttypes.h>
  #else
  typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
  typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
  typedef unsigned long uint32_t;
  typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;
  #endif
```

It is not portable, of course. But it might work for your compiler.

Comment: Needed these for Kernel Driver (C), It compiles! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

if it happened when you include opencv header.

I would recommand that change the order of headers.

put the opencv headers just below the standard C++ header.

like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with opencv? This is a very general error that happens in many circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in the base.mk file. The following 3rd line is important
`-include $(TOP)/defs.mk`

```
CFLAGS=$(DEBUG) -Wall -W -Wwrite-strings 
CFLAGS_C=-Wmissing-prototypes
CFLAGS_CXX=-std=c++0x
LDFLAGS=
LIBS=
```

to avoid the #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options

Comment: The question doesn't say whether Make is being used.  A more portable answer would just say which flags to pass to the compiler (and which compiler you're assuming).

Answer (score 1):

I had tha same problem trying to compile a lib I download from the internet. In my case, there was already a `#include <cstdint>` in the code. I solved it adding a:

```
using std::uint32_t;
```

Comment: @Daniel You still need to `#include` the correct header before you can access the type.

Comment: Yes, the `#include` is needed. I did not say it is not. But since in my case it was a `#include <cstdint>`, and there was no `using namespace std`, the compiler was not able to resolve the name `uint32_t`. So that is the reason I had to add the `using std::uint32_t;`

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for C++ code is to include this file:

```
#include <cstdint>
```

And use the integer types like this:

```
std::uint32_t
```

`uint32_t` is not guaranteed by the C++ standard to be available in `#include <cstdint>`, but `std::uint32_t` is.

This is the same for `std::size_t`, `std::int32_t`, `std::uint16_t`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

just navigate to /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits
open stdint-uintn.h and add these lines

```
typedef __uint8_t uint8_t;
typedef __uint16_t uint16_t;
typedef __uint32_t uint32_t;
typedef __uint64_t uint64_t;
```

again open stdint-intn.h  and add

```
typedef __int8_t int8_t;
typedef __int16_t int16_t;
typedef __int32_t int32_t;
typedef __int64_t int64_t;
```

note these lines are already present just copy and add the missing lines cheerss..

Comment: This is not a portable solution. And why would you include 4 lines when you could just include a single one in the form of `#include <stdint.h>` which is shorter and more portable and better in every way?

Answer (score -6):

You need to include iostream

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```